# Delphi: making two Chrome to run on two TPanel

Tags: delphi

I want to run two different instance of chrome into two TPanel of my form, for making a personal developing tool for test a realtime web editor with two different accounts.

My code isn't stable, sometimes chrome opens out of the TPanel and sometimes it works as expected.

```
unit WMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, ShellApi;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure RunInsideControl(AFileName, AParams, AClassName: String; AHParent: THandle);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.RunInsideControl(AFileName, AParams, AClassName : String; AHParent : THandle);
var
  aRec: TShellExecuteInfo;
  aAppHandle: integer;
const
  AVerb = 'open';
  ADir = '';
begin
  aAppHandle := 0;

  FillChar(aRec, SizeOf(aRec), #0);

  aRec.cbSize       := SizeOf(aRec);
  aRec.fMask        := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  aRec.lpVerb       := PChar( AVerb );
  aRec.lpFile       := PChar( AfileName );
  aRec.lpParameters := PChar( AParams );
  aRec.lpDirectory  := PChar( Adir );
  aRec.nShow        := SW_HIDE;

  ShellExecuteEx(@aRec);
  WaitForInputIdle(aRec.hProcess, 5000);

  while aAppHandle = 0 do begin
    aAppHandle := Winapi.Windows.FindWindow(PChar(AClassName), nil);
    Winapi.Windows.SetParent(aAppHandle, AHParent);
    SetWindowPos(aAppHandle, 0, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS);
    ShowWindow(aAppHandle, SW_SHOW);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RunInsideControl('Chrome.exe', '"https://stackoverflow.com"', 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1', Panel1.Handle);
  RunInsideControl('Chrome.exe', '-incognito "https://stackoverflow.com"', 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1', Panel2.Handle);
end;

end.
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off using an browser control (like TWebBrowser or DCEF) instead of embedding whole browser apps.

Comment: @UliGerhardt my web application works only on chrome

Comment: @ar099968 IMO you are trying to FindWindow too soon while the Chrome window does not yet exist.... FindWindow fails and Chrome starts unintercepted. WaitForInputIdle waits only for the process and not the process' window.

Comment: This is not going to work out in the long run. Give up now and use DCEF or some other Chromium based browser component. Cross process `SetParent` will bite you soon enough. Also, you leak the process handle, and you should use `CreateProcess` to, er, create a process. Of course, I'm advising you not to do that at all!

Comment: @ar099968 Then DCEF (embedded Chromium).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is just a tool for me... just for don't open two chrome and split it into the screen every time i need it...

Comment: Embedding the actual `Chrome` application inside your app when you have the full [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) available is kinda like towing a car to move it from one place to another rather than just making that car drive by itself. What happens if the user decides to kill the `Chrome.exe` process from the task manager, not realizing it's embedded in your app?

Comment: @JerryDodge, thanks, but it's is just a tool for me... Howeve, I'll take a look to chromium

Answer (score 0):

fixed myself... the problem is

```
SetWindowPos(aAppHandle, 0, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS);
ShowWindow(aAppHandle, SW_SHOW);
```

final code with resize handling:

```
unit WMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, ShellApi;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Splitter1: TSplitter;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Panel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Panel2Resize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FApp1: integer;
    FApp2: integer;
    function RunInsideControl(AFileName, AParams, AClassName : String; AHParent : THandle): THandle;
    procedure SizeMove(var msg: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;



var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm2.RunInsideControl(AFileName, AParams, AClassName : String; AHParent : THandle): THandle;
var
  aRec: TShellExecuteInfo;
  aAppHandle: integer;
const
  AVerb = 'open';
  ADir = '';
begin
  aAppHandle := 0;

  FillChar(aRec, SizeOf(aRec), #0);

  aRec.cbSize       := SizeOf(aRec);
  aRec.fMask        := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  aRec.lpVerb       := PChar( AVerb );
  aRec.lpFile       := PChar( AfileName );
  aRec.lpParameters := PChar( AParams );
  aRec.lpDirectory  := PChar( Adir );
  aRec.nShow        := SW_HIDE;

  ShellExecuteEx(@aRec);
  WaitForInputIdle(aRec.hProcess, 5000);

  while aAppHandle = 0 do begin
    aAppHandle := Winapi.Windows.FindWindow(PChar(AClassName), nil);
    Winapi.Windows.SetParent(aAppHandle, AHParent);
    // SetWindowPos(aAppHandle, 0, 0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS);
    // ShowWindow(aAppHandle, SW_SHOW);
  end;
  Result := aAppHandle;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FApp1 := RunInsideControl('Chrome.exe', '"https://stackoverflow.com/"', 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1', Panel1.Handle);
  FApp2 := RunInsideControl('Chrome.exe', '-incognito "https://stackoverflow.com/"', 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1', Panel2.Handle);

  Panel1.Width := Trunc( Screen.Width / 2 );
  ShowWindowAsync(Handle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsWindow(FApp1) then SetWindowPos(FApp1, 0, 0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS);
  if IsWindow(FApp2) then SetWindowPos(FApp2, 0, 0, 0, Panel2.Width, Panel2.Height, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS);
end;

procedure TForm2.Panel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormResize(nil);
end;

procedure TForm2.Panel2Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormResize(nil);
end;

Procedure TForm2.SizeMove(var msg: TWMSize);
begin
 inherited;
 if (msg.SizeType = SIZE_MAXIMIZED) OR (msg.SizeType = SIZE_RESTORED) then FormResize(nil);
end;

end.
```